# How to confirm password in android?

Tags: android, passwords, password-confirmation

I have two EditTexts, one for entering password and other for confirm this password.Maximum length of these edittexts are 5.

```
confirmPwdEdiText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
     int after) { }

 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count)        
 {

   String pwd = passwordEdiText.getText().toString();
   String confirmaion = charSequence.toString();
   if ((pwd == null || pwd.trim().length() <= 0) &&  confirmaion.trim().length() > 0) {
           Toast.makeText(context,"Enter password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } 
   else if (pwd != null && pwd.trim().length() > 0 ) {
      if(confirmaion.trim().length() == pwd.length()) {
         if (pwd.equals(confirmaion)) {
            password = pwd;
            Toast.makeText(context,"Passwords match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         } 
         else {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Passwords do not match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
      }
   }
 }
});
```

When i am using this for confirm password the  'Passwords do not match' toast shows again when deleting the password.How can i confirm password in an efficient way **without  using button click or any  other** ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: use to store password in shared preference & check on button click with shared preference file.

Comment: I am sorry.I edited my code.Please check it.How to confirm password using TextWatcher?

Comment: replace pwd with charSequence... bcz this ur string

Answer (score 1):

You can add one button and onClick Listener of button validate your password.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TextWatcher

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Comment: I know that.My question is how to confirm password?

Answer (score 1):

refer this simple sample you will get clue
its simple logic of comparing old password with new pass if both strings are not null or empty and in else if checking the length of old and new password length and comparing both password are equal.

this can be used if you choose simple validation

```
    @Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    System.out.println(s.toString());
    String oldPass = oldPassword.getText().toString();
    String newPass = newPassword.getText().toString();
    String confirmPass = confirmPassword.getText().toString();
    if (!oldPass.equals("") && !newPass.equals("") && oldPass.equals(newPass)) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Choose Different Password than Old Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (!newPass.equals("") && !confirmPass.equals("") && !newPass.equals(confirmPass) && newPass.length()==confirmPass.length())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Choose same as New Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: add the length condition in if loop

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: comment here for any other logic You need

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        private boolean checkPasswordNotMatch() {
            String pass=signupInputPassword.getText().toString();
            String cpass=signupInputPassword2.getText().toString();
            if (!pass.equals(cpass)) {
                signupInputLayoutPassword2.setErrorEnabled(true);
                signupInputLayoutPassword2.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_password_confirm));
                signupInputLayoutPassword.setErrorEnabled(true);
                signupInputLayoutPassword.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_password_confirm));
                return false;
        }
            signupInputLayoutPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
```